# textfile with line break into dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge textfile that looks like:

```
19990613,1\n19921209,1\n19940414,1\n19900506,1\n19910521,1\n19881124,0\n19760730,1\n19711206,1\n19890303,1\n19780127,0\n19860207
```

desired dataframe:

```
date          gender
1999-06-13      1
1992-12-09      1
```

and so on..

I've tried reading lines in python however it gives me IOPub data rate exceeded.

If I cannot convert it straight to df, it is fine to read line by line into a list then into df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me working `lineterminator`, `names` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv('text.txt', lineterminator='\\', names=['date','gender'])
```

Then remove `n` and parse to datetimes:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.lstrip('n'))
print (df)
         date  gender
0  1999-06-13       1
1  1992-12-09       1
2  1994-04-14       1
3  1990-05-06       1
4  1991-05-21       1
5  1988-11-24       0
6  1976-07-30       1
7  1971-12-06       1
8  1989-03-03       1
9  1978-01-27       0
10 1986-02-07       0
```

Comment: where did pd.compat.stringIO(temp) come from? it worked with pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp))

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable this is what is returned when I did pd.read_csv('text.txt', names=["date", "gender"], parse_dates=[0])

Comment: @makewhite - in last version of pandas was `pd.compat.stringIO` removed.

Comment: @makewhite -  If use only `df = pd.read_csv('text.txt')` it working?

Comment: even if I input with all parameters it doesn't work.

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200639/discussion-between-jezrael-and-makewhite).

Comment: it works however on first column all cells have "n" in front except for first row.

Comment: @makewhite - so if use `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.lstrip('n'))` it not remove it?

Comment: oh yes I can remove it. I was just telling you that there are "n" in front